# Expresso Store skipping order numbers

Tags: expresso-store

I have Expresso Store set up with PayPal Express as the payment method. Everything seems to be working fine but sometimes there are gaps in the order numbers.

For example, I'll get order #19, 20, 21 and then it will skip a couple and the next order number I receive will be #24.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happens when you have someone that goes through the order process but does not complete the order. You can goto Store > Orders then sort by the status of "Incomplete" you will probably see the missing order numbers.